list editor with valuesURL gets 403 (no credentials sent)
I am communicating wuth a backend application that provides the data.
To handle css issues I use in the config
  ajaxURL: url,
      ajaxConfig: {
        method: "GET",
        credentials: "include",
      },

so far this works.
For a list editor i am using valuesURL
but when the list editor calls the backend, it gets 403 because no credentials are sent.
can I force tabulator on calling the valuesURl to use some parameter, if so, how?
kind regards
Randy
So I tried to dynamically get values for a list editor, but tabulator does not resend credentials as in the ajax request for data.
I would expect to get the list options instead of 403.
